# Does ASP.NET MVC and WCF Web API use the same routing module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, wcf-web-api

Does ASP.NET MVC and WCF Web API use the same routing module for routing incoming requests to particular class methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the WCF Web API uses the ASP.NET routing engine (which by the way is not specific to ASP.NET MVC, it could be used in classic web forms applications as well).

Comment: When hosting on IIS, Web API uses the same routing engine to select the endpoint. However, this usage is not mandatory (e.g. self-hosting)